# c# windows forms - limited number of forms?

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I have a problem concerning c# and Windows Forms.

I am developing an application which needs more than 10 forms.

I started to close forms by clicking buttons and start new forms. It works quite well.

But now I am in form no. 5. I can't link any button with this new form...
In earlier forms, it worked??

Is there a limit on a number of forms?

Thanks for your help!

Greetings from Germany

Code: here it works

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form3: Form
    {
        public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
            Form4 f4 = new Form4();
            f4.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Code: here it isn't working

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form4: Form
    {
        public Form4()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
            Form3 f3 = new Form3();
            f3.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                this.Hide();
                Form5 f5 = new Form5();
                f5.ShowDialog();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Explain what “I can't link any button with this new form” means.

Comment: I'm not following.  You have a form, a user clicks a button and you hide the form the button was on and then pop up another form modally.  What happens when the user clicks `OK`, `Cancel` or `Close` on the dialog?  There's no place for control to return to.  The original form is hidden (and, hence, inoperative).  The modal form is dismissed.  Your UI is gone.  What are you trying to achive?  `this.Hide(); otherForm.ShowDialog();` is an odd construct, and I don't understand why you'd do that.

Comment: Is the `this.Hide(); otherForm.ShowDialog();` there so that the user can only interact with the new form and not with the one that popped it up.  If so, skip the `Hide` call and instead call `ShowDialog` with `this` as an argument: `ShowDialog(this);`.  That overload of `ShowDialog` will pop up the dialog and not allow anyone access to the originating form.  It's also usually useful to check the return value of `ShowDialog`.  It can tell you how your user dismissed the dialog (`OK`, `Cancel`, etc.)

Comment: No, there's no limit, but there's a limit on resources, so try to ensure that you dispose things which are IDisposable. For example `Form3 f3 = new Form3();` and things like that should be in a `using` block. This won't be the cause of your issue but it's good practice.

Comment: Did you copy and paste your code?  Event handlers don't automatically get wired up if you do that.  Make sure your event handlers are subscribed.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact that you're using `Hide()` instead of `Close()`.

If you use the `Hide()` function, it just sets the form's property `Visibility.Hidden`, which means that the Form is still running on the background.

Now, when you call the function from `Form4` to "Close" and open `Form3`, you're just hidding `Form4`, if you want to call `Form4` back, you're gonne create two `Form4` (of the same Type), since it's still in the background.

One way I like to do that is to check if the form is open before creating a new one:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
        var app = Application.OpenForms["Form3"];
        if (app == null)
        {
            Form3 f3 = new Form3();
            f3.Show();
        }
        else {  app.Show(); app.BringToFront(); }
    }
```

Or you can just call a new Form, but make sure you Close the form.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
        Form3 f3 = new Form3();
        f3.Show();
    }
```